# A question on dual spaces of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been doing a bit of self study into the formalism of dual spaces. In the book that I've been reading the author introduces the notion of a dual space, $V^{\ast}$ to a given vector space $V$ as the set of linear functionals $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ which map $V$ to its underlying field $\mathbb{F}$ such that $$f\left(\mathbf{v} +\mathbf{w}\right) = f\left(\mathbf{v}\right) +f\left(\mathbf{w} \right)\quad\forall\;\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in V$$ and $$f\left(c\mathbf{v}\right) = cf\left(\mathbf{v}\right)$$ The author then goes on to introduce an ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = \lbrace\mathbf{e}_{i}\rbrace _{i=1, \ldots , n}$ for the vector space $V$ such that for a given $\mathbf{v} \in V$ $$\mathbf{v}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}v^{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}= v^{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}+ \cdots + v^{n}\mathbf{e}_{n}$$ and then defines the $i^{th}$ dual basis vector $\mathfrak{e}^{i}$ as a linear functional that satisfies $$\mathfrak{e}^{i}\left(\mathbf{v}\right) = f\left( v^{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}+ \cdots + v^{n}\mathbf{e}_{n}\right) = v^{i}$$
such that the linear functional $\mathfrak{e}^{i}$ "picks off" the $i^{th}$ component of the vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$.

Is there any particular motivation behind this? Or do we just choose the functional this way such that the basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ and their corresponding dual basis vectors $\mathfrak{e}^{j}$ satisfy $$\mathfrak{e}^{i}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right) = \delta^{i}_{j}$$

Answer (score 3):

> Do we just choose the functional this way such that the basis vectors ei and their corresponding dual basis vectors $\mathfrak e^j$ satisfy
>   $$
> \mathfrak e^i(e_j)= \delta _{ij}
> $$

Yes, that's exactly the reason.  This, in particular, makes computation extremely easy.

If $f = \sum_{i}a_i \mathfrak e^i$ and $v = \sum_j b_j e_j$, then we have
$$
f(v) = \sum_{i} a_i b_i
$$
Which you may think of as being tantamount to a "dot product".  What we're doing here is ostensibly the same as selecting an "orthonormal basis" in a situation where we've forgone the notion of an inner product.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do we just define it this way to guarantee a mapping that preserves linear independence such that we can form a basis for the dual space?

Comment: What do you mean by "a mapping that preserves linear independence"?   Why would we want to/ have to guarantee such a thing?

Comment: Sorry, this was a bit of a faux-pas on my part, I wrote it late last night and didn't really think it through properly! I guess I was trying to justify in my mind a bit more why we have such a definition for a dual vector?!

Comment: Why wouldn't we have such a definition for a dual vector?  I'm trying to understand what it is that you feel the need to justify.  Perhaps the following will help: for any functional $f$ on a finite dimensional inner product space, there must exist a vector $v$ such that for any $v$, $f(v) = \langle u, v\rangle$.

Comment: I think I was just expecting there to be a bit more motivation behind the definition to be given in the text, but as far as I understand (from the text and what you've said) we choose a set of linear functionals which satisfy this property and call this the dual vector space to a given vector space, $V$. I guess the crux of my confusion really is, what is a dual space to a given vector space and what is the motivation behind it?

Comment: *"we choose a set of linear functionals which satisfy this property and call this the dual vector space to V"*.  No, the dual space is defined as being the space of **all** functionals over $V$.  Any functional over $V$, as it ends up, can be written as a linear combination of the elements in our dual basis.  "That property" is just what linearity means.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I appreciate your help and patience in explaining. Would it be correct to say that the notion of a dual space is introduced to enable one to determine the components of a vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ in cases where the coordinate frame is non-Cartesian and, more generally, (as you said) when we have forgone the notion of an inner product between two vectors?

Comment: That's a reasonable way to think about it, certainly in the finite dimensional case.  As a matter of fact, I think it is the practice in certain fields to refer to elements of the relevant dual space as "coordinate functions" (as in "functions that give you a certain coordinate of a vector"), but I'd have to double check that.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for doing this is to mimic the inner product

Often one writes $\langle v,f \rangle$ for $f(v)$ where $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$. Note that for a general Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, all liner functionals are given by inner products, i.e. we have a correspondence of a linear functional $\phi$ with a vector $x \in \mathcal{H} $(Riesz representation theorem). So, in this case, an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space will become an orthonormal basis of the dual space under the identification $\mathcal{H^*}$ with $\mathcal{H}$.

In case of a general vectors space (with or without the structure of norm, inner product etc) we would still like to think of $f(v)$ as "$\langle v,f \rangle$", i.e. some sort of inner product pairing. This intuitive notion makes a lot of sense in calculation- and makes computations really easy- and one can use the intuitions from the Hilbert space setting in this case to "guess" and prove certain formula.

I can write a few more examples if you want- so let me know in comments- so that I can come back and edit the answer.

Comment: Cheers, that's very useful. Is there any way to prove the relation $\mathfrak{e}^{i}\left(\mathbf{e}_{j}\right)= \delta^{i}_{j}$, or is this just a definition that we use so we can guarantee a mapping that preserves linear independence of a set of vectors so that we have a basis for the dual space?

Comment: @Will: It's a definition :).

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Forgot to say, would appreciate a few more examples if you have the time. Thanks :)